# Elasticsearch Nested Filter by Max

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following documents stored in elasticsearch:

```
{
  run_number: 3,
  vendor: v_a,
  data: blah
},
{
  run_number: 2,
  vendor: v_b,
  data: blah
},
{
  run_number: 2,
  vendor: v_b,
  data: blah2
},
{
  run_number: 1,
  vendor: v_a,
  data: blah
},
{
  run_number: 1,
  vendor: v_b,
  data: blah
}
```

I am trying to run a search query against this that returns the documents for the most recent run for each vendor. In this example, I want to return the first 3 documents (since they have the max 'run_number' for the given vendor).

My current query is:

```
{
"size": 500,
"aggs": {
    "group_by_vendor": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "vendor"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "max_run_number": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "run_number",
                    "order": {"_term": "desc"},
                    "size": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

But the max_run_number aggregation with size = 1 only limits the nested buckets that are returned. This still returns all hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) here

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
"group_by_vendor": {
    "terms": {
        "field": "vendor"
    },
    "aggs": {
        "max_run_number": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "run_number",
                "order": {"_term": "desc"},
                "size": 1
            },
            "aggs" : {
              "top hits agg" : {
                "top_hits" : {
                 "size" :3   
                }
              }
            }
        }
      }
    } 
   }
  }
```